# Getting info from all related objects in django

Tags: python, django, templates, object, view

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, but I'm new to Django. I have a quiz system set up for an experiment I'm running.

The relevant entries in models.py follow:

```
class Flavor(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Passage(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class PassageText(models.Model):
  passage = models.ForeignKey(Passage)
  flavor = models.ForeignKey(Flavor)
  contents = models.TextField()

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "[%s#%s]" % (self.passage, self.flavor)

class Question(models.Model):
  passage = models.ForeignKey(Passage)
  text = models.TextField()

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "[%s#%s]" % (self.passage, self.text)

class AnswerOption(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
  text = models.TextField()
  is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "[%s#%s]" % (self.question, self.text)

class TestSubject(models.Model):
  GENDER_CHOICES = ( ('M','Male'), ('F','Female'), )
  EDUCATION_CHOICES = ( ('SH', 'Some high school'), ('HS', 'High school diploma'), ('SC', 'Some college'), ('CD', 'College degree'), ('MD', 'Master\'s degree'), ('PH','PhD or higher education'), )
  GPA_CHOICES = ( ('1', '1.0-1.5'), ('2', '1.5-2.0'), ('3', '2.0-2.5'), ('4', '2.5-3.0'), ('5', '3.0-3.5'), ('6', '3.5-4.0'), ('7', '4.0-4.5'), ('8', '4.5-5.0'), )

  ip = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  created_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
  time_used = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='number of seconds used for test')

  age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
  education = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES)
  school = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  grad_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  gpa = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GPA_CHOICES)
  sat_verbal = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
  sat_math = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
  sat_writing = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
  sat_overall = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
  english_is_your_first_language = models.BooleanField()
  kerberos_name_if_applying_for_900_credit = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "[%s#%s]" % (self.ip, self.created_time)

class TestSequence(models.Model):
  subject = models.ForeignKey(TestSubject)
  order = models.IntegerField(help_text='1..n')
  pt = models.ForeignKey(PassageText)
  time_used = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='number of seconds used for test')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "[%s#%d]" % (self.subject, self.order)

class QuestionSequence(models.Model):
  tseq = models.ForeignKey(TestSequence)
  order = models.IntegerField(help_text='0..n')
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
  selectedanswer = models.ForeignKey(AnswerOption, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "[%s#%d]" % (self.tseq, self.order)
```

I want to essentially have a page that just gives me a table of all TestSubject objects (and all their properties) as well as a list of which passages they did and a count of how many questions they got right in that passage.

Comment: Are you looking for somebody to code you a solution? Which aspect of your question are you having the most trouble with, is it accessing the data, or presenting it to the user? Your question could be more specific.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to code me a solution, sorry. I suppose I should clarify what I'm unclear about: I can loop through all the TestSubject objects in views.py or pass a list of them to the template, but if I loop through them in the template, I'm unclear as to how to get the related passages and answers for each testsubject.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one has helped you yet, here:

```
# *snip* -- view:
context = { 'test_subjects' : TestSubject.objects.all() }
return render_to_response('Template', context)
# *snip*

# *snip* -- template:
{% for test_subject in test_subjects %}
{{ test_subject.ip }}
{# ... snip ... #}
{% empty %}
There are no test subjects.
{% endfor %}
```

secondly, it **is** more preferable to pass a list of "things" to a template and let it do the magic... unless you have some special reason not to do so. Passing them in as a string by "converting" and "joining" them in the view ruins the separation between data and code, and it makes your views "dirty".

For more information on this subject, read: [Views](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/), [Templates](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/) and [Models](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/)

On a side note, I think it would be better if you rethought some parts of your model design, I see some redundancy there. Storing the test subject's name would be a good and user friendly idea. Finally, shouldn't `flavor` be `flavour`? Even if you don't change it in your code, you might want to I18N it for British English speakers.

Comment: I totally agree with the passing of a list of "things" to a template. I can't store the name as it is supposed to be an anonymous quiz.

This part (the listing of the test subjects) is the part I already had. What I'm unclear about is how to get the template to list each passage for each subject, for example. And then how to get the count of correct answers for each passage for each subject. Make sense?

Comment: @michael: no. I'm guessing you want to show each test subject a number of questions and want to validate the answers and grade them? (If this is what you want, then be more specific about your problem, what have you tried till now). Secondly, what answers are you talking about?